# CPU- upgrade-to-macbookair

Tags: macbook-pro

My Mac Book Air's CPU has an Intel 1.23 GHz. In order to upgrade "flashplayer" I need a 1.33 GHz CPU or faster.
How can I remove the current CPU and wire in a replacement?

Comment: Weird that I can't find any model of Air with 1.23 GHz CPU.

Comment: There is no MacBook Air model with 1.23 GHz. http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/index-macbook-air.html

Answer (score 1):

It's reasonable to assume you can't. The processor is not a serviceable component in a MacBook Air.

Answer (score 0):

The requirement [from this page](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/flash-player-needed-acrobat-reader.html) is for a Core2 Duo 1.33 GHz CPU or faster. Your Air's i series processor is a newer architecture than a Core2, and is considerably faster than the requirement.